# Why doesn't this code print the given rows from the table?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

This code should iterate through the table from the database and manipulate the data and print it in the given format. I need to explain why it doesn't actually do this, 
running the code doesn't do anything,
does anyone have any thoughts?

```
def count_columns(table_name):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + table_name)
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        if len(row) == "2":
            print("ID: ", row,[0], "Category: ", row[1])
        elif len(row) == "3":
            print("ID: ", row,[0], "Range: ", row[1], "Category: ", row[2])
        elif len(row) == "4":
            print("ID: ", row,[0], "Systolic: ", row[1], "Diastolic: ", row[2], "Category: "
```

Comment: What's `cur`?..

Comment: Can you check if cur.execute does actually select anything? Please print (len(row)). If it's less than 2 or bigger than 4, you won't catch the result with your if-statement.

Comment: You're comparing integers with a string in those `len(rows) == "x"` lines and well ... since a string will never ever equal any number nothing is executed. Just drop the quotation marks.

Comment: @Lupacante He is using `pyodbc` or simmilar to interface to the database, `cur` is the cursor that you create, something like a session

Comment: @MarcelZoll I was hoping to hint at them that they should write a minimal working example ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `len(row)` is never exactly equal to `'2'`, `'3'`, or `'4'`, which are `strings`.

`len` returns an int; if you remove the quotes, it may work.

Comment: (or alternatively, also, the `cur.fetchall()` fails)

Comment: Yes, however, you probably mean additionally, because `len` will not return a `string`